# How do you put an array into a string and then index the string using laravel 5

Tags: php, database, split, type-conversion, laravel-5

Ok, So I'm running to this problem i"m trying to split/ index the values in a column in my database.  So i put the I've been trying to put it into a string, and all the combination I have tried should work, but everytime I try to split the value i keep getting this error `Array to string conversion` and the errors shows my database as appose to a string or even at the very least a column.   Now sorry if my code at this point looks like more work than it should be haha.  That was out of desperation and a attempt to get it to work.

this my controller:

```
public function FSC_List($id)
{

    $fsg_find_id = fsgdata::find($id);
    $fsc_list_all = fscdata::all();
    $fsc_find_id = fscdata::find($id);
    $num_match = fscdata::all()->toArray();
    $fsc_num_col = fscdata::lists('fsc_number');
    $newstring = implode("",$fsc_num_col);
    $final = $newstring.str_split(0,2); 

return View('FSC_views.FSC_List', compact('fsg_find_id','fsc_list_all',
        'fsc_find_id', 'num_match', 'fsc_num_col', 'newstring','final'));
}
```

This is my view:

```
@extends('layout.master')
@section('content')
<div class="figure"><img src="/Content/images/figure2.jpg" /></div>
<div class="main">
    <h2>Search Results for FSG Number: {{ $fsg_find_id->fsg_number }}</h2>
        <ul>

        @foreach($fsc_num_col as $fsc_find_id->fsg_number)
            @if($fsg_find_id->fsg_number == $final);
                <a href='/NSN_list={{ $fsc_find_id->id }}'>{{$fsc_find_id->fsc_number}}</a></br>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endsection
```

Note my goal is to have 2 numbers chosen by the users to match up with the first 2 digits of a bunch of 4 digit numbers in a database and to grab all of those that meet that criteria.  Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate issue looks like this line:

```
$final = $newstring.str_split(0,2);
```

Basically, you are trying to combine a string `$newstring` with an array `str_split(0, 2)` which is why you are getting the `Array to string conversion` error.  Take a look at the manual entry for [str_split](http://php.net/str_split) - it doesn't look like you understand it properly.

If you are trying to get the first two characters of a string then you should be using [substr](http://php.net/substr). Something like:

```
$full_string = 'abcdefg';
$first_two = substr($full_string, 0, 2);  # $first_two = 'ab'
```

Answer (score 0):

this is probably not the best practice, but this is how I went about it, if anyone knows how to index more than one character at a time, by all means share haha.

```
@foreach($fsc_list_all as $fsc_find_id)
    @if($fsg_find_id->fsg_number[0] == $fsc_find_id->fsc_number{0} &&
      $fsg_find_id->fsg_number[1] == $fsc_find_id->fsc_number{1})

          <a href='/NSN_list={{ $fsc_find_id->id }}'>{{$fsc_find_id->fsc_number}}</a></br>

     @endif
@endforeach
```